# table-like widget or control which content can be edited

Tags: .net, user-interface, compact-framework

is there any **table-like** widget or control which content can be **edited** in the **.NET Compact Framework** 2.0 using Visual Studio 2005? (we **could** change to a newer version if it need to be)

Otherwise it would be okay if it is possible to identify the column and row in an `onClick`-event to open an `TextBox`.

I'm afraid I found nothing in the documentation about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resco offers an [editable grid control for the CF](http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/overview.aspx). ComponentOne [also offers one](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/FlexGridMobileDevices/).

If you're more of a do-it-yourselfer, then you cna use the data grid extensions. An example for them [can be found here](http://www.ehartwell.com/InfoDabble/DataGrid_extensions_for_the_Compact_Framework).